# Bad project type: ionic-angular when building Ionic3 project

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

Building an ionic 3 project using Ionic CLI 7.0.1 and above fails with the error message

> Bad project type: ionic-angular

when running the build command

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

or running the command

```
ionic --version
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the project type has to be changed from

`ionic-angular` to `angular` in the configuration file
`ionic.config.json` in your ionic home folder which is the default value from ionic 4.

In the json file please change

```
 "type": "ionic-angular",
```

to

```
"type": "angular",
```